# Average overlapping area of 2 triangles on a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, random

2 triangles which both have their vertices on the same circle with radius *r* are randomly picked. What is the average area formed by the 2 triangles overlapping? For example, the 2 triangles can not overlap at all or overlap each other completely. If they share only a vertex or a side, they don't count as overlapping each other. This came up as a "shower thought" and I have no idea where to even begin to solve it...

Comment: No idea if this'll help, but [this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleTrianglePicking.html) studies the area of one randomly chosen triangle inscribed in the unit circle. The intersection of two triangles is a lot more complicated, so the integrals involved might become unreasonable, but it could be a start.

Comment: As usual you need to define probability of events. I think you could fix the location of one triangle and than allow the other to be placed randomly.